# MS dynamics and MS Project Application

Tags: dynamics-crm, ms-project

My comany is using MS Project to handle ERP.

But after a quick search on internet, I found out MS Dynamics is the tool dedicated for ERP.

So just wondering what's the difference between MS Dynamics and MS Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Project is intended for project management. ERP is intended for all operations internal to a business, including accounts payable and receivable, stock control, manufacturing, risk management, supply chain, etc, etc, etc. It often includes project management as well.

So they're entirely different things.

MS Dynamics is a group of several products, not a single product and includes ERP and CRM products.

Answer (score 0):

Well said Mike. MS Dynamics is a group of products for ERP and CRM like NAV (formerly known as Navision) which is an ERP solution for small and mid size enterprises. [Microsoft Project](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us) is a project management software which is designed to assist project managers in developing plans, assigning resources to tasks, tracking progress, managing budgets and analyzing workloads.